# Word VBA - format and re-link footnotes and endnotes in hyperlinks

Tags: vba, string, replace, ms-word, hyperlink

I need to find footnote and endnote marks (in the body, to format them and re-link them)  etc, in a macro I have written to clean up documents imported from the web.

My macro works fine, *except* where part of the find string is hyperlink display text and part is not.

Searching for `([a-z])([0-9])` (to locate endnote marks in the body, as they are not formatted as endnotes) does not find them because `[0-9]` is hyperlink display text and `[a-z]` is not.

1. My question here: how to *search* for [normal string] adjacent to [hyperlink display text string]?
2. If found, the next step is how to replace the hyperlink display text (format endnotes superscript, delete the para mark)  keeping it in the hyperlink (I can work on that - maybe the subject of another question?)

Comment: Presumably, your hyperlinks are still pointing to some web address, in which case you should be unlinking them before doing your Find/Replace. You may also be interested in: https://www.msofficeforums.com/40799-post4.html & https://www.msofficeforums.com/110511-post2.html

Comment: Thank you Paul, De-linking is a perfect solution for the footnote or endnote marks (they are plain text without superscript or brackets so I can't see how to make your brilliant macros work), but not for other hyperlinks containing para marks - I need to keep those links :) - any further ideas? Vicki

Comment: If I could find all hyperlinks containing a number only and superscript them maybe your macros would work? (Strangely, the marks in the endnotes themselves are superscript, while in the body they are normal style.

Comment: The macros in the links I posted would likely require the unlinking to be done beforehand. You can unlink every field via Ctrl-A, F9. Or you could use a macro to unlink just hyperlinks whose display text is numeric. I'm curious, though as to why you'd have references in the [a-z][0-9] format.

Comment: I am having trouble working out a macro which acts only on display text containing a number only, (and would it catch auto paragraph numbering which also displays numbers only?) ... In answer to your question, my endnote marks do contain only numbers, I was being clever trying to find the marks by searching for numbers not separated from the preceding text... hence my original question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, of course, simply convert your hyperlinks to superscripted numbers then use whatever other code you have to replace the superscripted numbers with endnotes.

```
Sub Demo()
Dim h As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For h = .Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Hyperlinks(h)
      If IsNumeric(.TextToDisplay) = True Then
        With .Range
          If .Characters.First.Previous Like "[a-z]" Then
            .Fields.Unlink
            .Font.Reset
            .Font.Superscript = True
          End If
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Depending on what you're doing, you could simply insert your endnoting code into the inner If ... End If construct in place of the font manipulations.

Comment: Many thanks for this alternative solution for endnotes!  Are you able to help with an answer to my question, which I still need, to find duplicate paragraphs and other cleanup issues? 
(I was going to re-title this question and open a separate one for my original question, but for some reason I have been prevented from posting - "question limit reached", although this is the only question I've posted in several months. :(

Comment: «Are you able to help with an answer to my question, which I still need, to find duplicate paragraphs and other cleanup issues?» You really should start a separate thread for that. Duplicate paragraph breaks can be cleaned up by a fairly simple Find/Replace. See also: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/29880-cleaning-text-pasted-websites-mails-pdfs-etc.html

Comment: «Duplicate paragraph breaks can be cleaned up by a fairly simple Find/Replace»  ^13^13 is NOT FOUND if one of them is hyperlink display text and the other is not. That is my question. Are you able to assist with the find/replace code which will find them? I have refocussed the examples in my question although it was clear in the heading and the question at the end.

Comment: «Many thanks for this alternative solution for endnotes!» - I upvoted your answer as helpful, but it does not answer my question as per the title.

Comment: « it does not answer my question as per the title» The simple reason for that is that Find does not work that way. I explained the need for the unlinking in my very first comment in this thread.

Comment: «Find does not work that way» - yes, as I observed in my question.  «I explained the need for the unlinking» - as I said in my comment, I do not want to unlink hyperlinks (other than the broken endnote ones and you provided the solution for that), so EITHER I would need to reconstruct every type of hyperlink after unlinking (cross references, URLs, bookmarks in the doc), OR some sort of loop to find and edit the mixed strings which might be easier?

Comment: -OR, (in the case of paragraphs only), remove all paragraph marks at the beginning and end of display text fields?

Comment: If your hyperlinks contain paragraph breaks in the display text, the code I posted above can readily be adapted to remove those paragraph breaks by editing the display text. The questions remain, though: (a) does this affect only the 'endnote' hyperlinks or do you want to change others, too; and (b) where do you want the paragraph breaks to go? In any event, as you opined in your first post, StackOverflow rules require that topic to be dealt with as a separate question.

Comment: separate question posted :)

Comment: My apologies, I do not know how to modify your excellent macro to find and delete only paragraph marks which are the last character in the display text? (I have done a macro which replaces all display text paragraph marks; but sometimes they are needed in the body of the display text))